# Issue while installing Windows 10 on an early 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I try to install a bootcamp with :

- OSX 10.11 El Capitan
- Windows 10 Pro (from Dreamspark system, its a license for students)

I have succeeded in installing the Windows 10 .iso file on my USB stick.  I had to edit the *plist* file of the Boot Camp Assistant (the last version 6.0). I have succeeded in partitioning my SSD in two parts.

Now I boot on the USB stick by pushing ALT when booting. The install process asks me to enter the license key. I precise that the installation process looks like the old one, the Windows 7's one. After the license has been entered, I have an error :

> tabtip.exe - Application error
>
> The exception unknown software exception (some hexadecimal) occurred in the program at location (some hexadecimal)
>
> Click on OK to terminate the program

After clicking OK, I can just cancel the installation.

I have tried to copy again Windows 10 on the USB stick. It doesn't change anything.

I have also tried to avoid entering my license key by using the "next" button of the window, but the error occurs just after.

I have tried to install Windows 8.1, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the optical drive to install Windows 10? I assume you are trying to do a BIOS/MBR install and not  a EFI/GPT install? What version of the Boot Camp Support Software are you using? Have you tried installing the iso using a free copy of VirtualBox to see if that works? If you do, do NOT activate the software. In fact, I would not use the product key to test in Virtual Box.

Comment: - I do not use the optical drive because I changed it with a HDD. I am far away from my house for 1 year so I can't use the USB optical drive too.

 - I'm trying to do a EFI/GPT install I think, but I'm not sure.

 - I'm using the last version of Boot Camp Support, I suppose its uploaded with Boot Camp Assistant ?

 - I've not tried with VirtualBox, I would want to have a real dual boot. What does a virtual box test will teach us ?

Answer (score 1):

don't try to force boot using EFI if you have MBP early 2011, I have and it succeeded but without sound. the only way to fix the sound problem is to re install it in BIOS boot not EFI

Answer (score 0):

- Usually, if you had to edit the *plist* file, then you can not install
  using a USB.
- You may be able to do a EFI/GPT install, but you have a **FAR BETTER
  CHANCE** of succeeding with a BIOS/MBR install.
- According to Apple, your model does not support Windows 10. Well, my
  model does not support Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 in 64 bit mode and
  this has not stopped me yet. They all run just fine. You can try
  using the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Boot Camp Support
  Software (BCSS) for your model. An alternative would be to use the 64
  bit Windows 7 BCSS as specified at [Install Windows 7 and earlier on
  your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016). The would be [Boot Camp Support
  Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US).

Virtual Box is a small sized application that can be used to verify your Windows iso is installable. Your probably is, so this step is not necessary. However, Virtual Box and be used as a substitute  for the Boot Camp Assistant. In other words, you can use VirtualBox to setup a dual boot. There are certain commands (convert, format, bootsect, bootrec, etc...) that do not exist under OS X. You can boot your Windows 10 iso using VirtualBox and execute these commands on disk images and ***physical*** partitions. This allows you to copy the files from the iso to a physical partition and boot from that instead of a DVD or USB flash drive. ***You never create or boot a Windows 10 virtual machine.***

One never really appreciates what effort and time the Boot Camp Assistant application saves you until you try installing Windows without it. The procedure for installing on a machine with an internal SDD and internal HHD is given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199843/how-do-i-install-windows-10-on-macbookpro5-1-with-no-optical-drive-ssdhdd/201980#201980).

> Others have posted problems with the SSD driver. Basically, they say the problem is with the Digital Signature. You may have to manually fix this problem. If the problem occurs, Let me know.

Comment: Does the Boot Camp Assistant permits to do a BIOS/MBR installation ? When I reboot my Mac I can see the USB stick with "EFI Boot" as name. I suppose its a EFI installation.
I will try with VirtualBox and physical partitions !

Comment: If you had an optical drive, I would assume when holding down alt/option key on startup, you would see both "Windows" and "EFI Boot". Selecting "Windows" causes an BIOS/MBR install. VirtualBox will selects BIOS/MBR by default, so you will not be prompted.

Comment: Which drives do you intend to install OS X and Windows 10 on? (The SDD or HDD?). Which drive is `disk0`? (You can click Info button in Disk Utility application to get the disk identifier.)

Comment: disk0 is the SSD for me

Comment: I found your tutorial on apple.stackexchange, do you think it is the only solution ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199843/how-do-i-install-windows-10-on-macbookpro5-1-with-no-optical-drive-ssdhdd/201980#201980

Comment: I tried this : I have linked my physical partition with a .vmdk and tried to launch the installation from Virtualbox directly with the ISO mounted on in. It has not changed anything. I know that my USB stick is not the problem

Comment: If you have VirtualBox installed, you might as well try installing Windows 10 into a Virtual Machine using a virtual partition. In other words, install using all the defaults in VirtualBox and see if the iso is any good. You should not need the product key if you have the Home or Pro editions.

Answer (score 0):

That probably won't be the only hurdle you'll have to take. I had Windows 7 running nice and smoothly for over 3 years on my Late 2011 MacBook Pro. I've literally never seen Windows run so smooth on a machine even after many years.

Then, ignoring the lack of support for Windows 10 for my model, I stubbornly upgraded to Windows 10 via Windows Update. During the upgrade I found out that the Bluetooth driver was incompatible. So I had to disable that in order to continue the upgrade (I wasn't using it much anyways, I figured).

Besides that I got frequent BSOD's, most of the time a few minutes after startup. I tried to upgrade all sorts of drivers, update / downgrade Bootcamp to a suitable version. I still get the blue screens.

My advice would be to either just install Windows 7 or wait till someone manages to succesfully install Windows 10 on a 2011 model (I haven't seen anyone on the net yet) and follow what they did. I'm doing the latter. I rarely give up on stuff like this, but I have for now.

To comment on the issue at hand: since tabtip.exe is a driver for tablet support and you probably won't need it I would try to remove that driver from the installation following the assumption that what isn't installed can't cause any problems. However I'm not sure if the installation depends on that driver being present. It may very well throw an error because the driver is missing. But that is what I would try in this situation.

```
[Insert accountability disclaimer]
```

Oh, and if you do remove the driver from the install, save it to another location so you can restore it if needed or it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

You could ofcourse also try a Windows 7 / 8.1 install first and try to upgrade for free from there on via Windows Update. You'll have to be quick though the free upgrade only lasts for a few more days I believe.