# Can't install Windows 7 on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I want to install Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro(15'' mid 2012 version). It seems like only Windows 8 can be installed. I was using Windows7 on this mac before. I have erased it and want to install it again but this happens. Can someone please help me?

Thank You

[image]

Comment: That's weird. What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Well if it was installed fine before it **may** be that you had an earlier version of BootCamp previously. And now the current, or latest version, that you have does not support Win7. Just guessing here.

Comment: Thx for you comment . I think so. I had downloaded an older version of bootcamp which is bootcamp 4 from apple and it did not work too. I am so upset. Is it possible to downgrade my OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve Chambers is right.

As Windows release new versions boot camp is updated to support them and more often than not they drop support for the previous version of Windows.

You could either install Windows 8.1 (it still has the start menu ;) ) or install Windows 7 under parallels desktop.

I personally use parallels desktop as it allows me to use Windows and Mac at the same time. I run it on my 2014 MacBook Pro retina. No issues, everything runs perfectly.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Mitchell. apple has only dropped windows7 bootcamp support in new mac right? but my mac is old version. It's version mid 2012 and it cant install windows7 too.... it's very disgusting.

Comment: Hello sengsian, what version of OS X are you using? This will determine whether you can run Windows 7 under boot camp or not, it doesn't depend on the age of the hardware itself

Comment: Hi, Thx for the reply. My OS X version in 10.8.5. If this version of OS X does not support Windows7 then can I downgrade it to the older version?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's web site [Install Windows 7 and earlier on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), you can still install Windows 7 on your Mac. Follow the instructions given at this site. You may have to upgrade your version of OS X.

In the event you want to keep your version of OS X and the Boot Camp Assistant will not let you install, you can use a free copy of Virtual Box to install Windows 7 directly from the ISO file. The procedure would be similar to my answer given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199843/how-do-i-install-windows-10-on-macbookpro5-1-with-no-optical-drive-ssdhdd/201980#201980). The difference is that you only have one internal drive and you do not need to enter Audit mode. If you what to attempt this procedure and have any questions let me know.