# Installing Windows on SSD in optical drive bay

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I removed my HDD from the main bay to install Windows 10 (through BootCamp) on my SSD (in the optical drive bay) and then I put back my HDD.

After that, I can't boot Windows anymore. Is there a way to fix it other than putting my SSD in the main drive bay?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a way to do this (I've got 2 drives and have been running this config for several years:  Mac OS on main drive, and FAT/winblows on optical bay)..

you have to first do the setup of the windows drive with it in the main bay (for some reason it won't recognize in the optical for purposes of BootCamp)...

Then after you've installed, you can move it over, then you can option-boot from it..
An added advantage of this setup is thatif you've got VMWare (fusion) you can also boot it as a virtualized OS from within Mac...

Comment: How did you do it exactly? I tried that. I installed Windows on the SSD while it was in the main bay and everything worked fine. As soon as I put it back in the optical bay and put the HDD in the main bay, I can't boot Windows anymore. There's just a black screen with a blinking cursor...

Comment: i'm guessing you didn't set up BootCamp properly, as that is what allows the OS to see the partition.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer where the optical drive was replaced with a hard disk drive (HDD) and the primary drive was a solid state drive (SSD). See [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199843/how-do-i-install-windows-10-on-macbookpro5-1-with-no-optical-drive-ssdhdd/201980#201980). I believe the procedure would still work for your configuration. You will not need to swap drives using my method. You will need to install a free copy of virtual box on your OS X disk.

Your question does not explain how you booted to the Windows installation media. Did you use an external DVD drive or a flash drive? In either case, have you tried booting to the Windows installation media and just executing steps 37 and 38 from the above link? Try preforming these steps with both drives installed in your Mac.